# How to initialize a: set<pair<string, string>>?

Tags: c++

in c++,
so I need to use the following:

```
set<pair<string, string>> info;
```

where the set info has pairs of strings within it. How can I initialize this info variable? I don't need to initialize it to anything specific. But just for the sake of initialization?

For example:

```
int i = 0;
```

Comment: You have already initialized it to be empty.

Answer (score 8):

`std::set` and `std::string` both have default constructors which properly initialize them as empty.  So you don't have to do anything special, your declaration is sufficient.

```
set<pair<string, string>> info;
```

If you want to initialize the set with some initial elements, and you are using C++11, you can do as follows:

```
set<pair<string,string>> info = {
    {"one","two"},
    {"three","four"},
    {"five","six"}
};
```

That will initialize the set with 3 pairs of strings. If you are not using C++11, just use `set::insert`.